# Defining functions inside loop redefine the function for every iteration or python can optimize that?

Tags: python

Sometimes I define temporary functions for convenience

```
def parse_time(string):
   h, m = string.split(':')
   return timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m)

something = parse_time(re.search(r'(\d\d:\d\d)', line).group(1))
```

This is okay, now I have the above snippet inside a loop:

```
for line in file:
   # ... some code

    def parse_time(string):
        h, m = string.split(':')
        return timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m)

    something = parse_time(re.search(r'(\d\d:\d\d)', line).group(1))
```

My question is, will python optimize this or it will redefine the function for each iteration? How can I verify that?

Regards,

Comment: It (re)defines it each iteration, but why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: You don't have to define the function inside the for loop in order to use it there.

Comment: I don't really need this, but sometimes I need a little function that I don't want to write as lambdas, and moving this tiny functions outer scope seems not desirable to me

Comment: Sometimes we encode variables in closures for emulating states with function calls, and, at last me, like the code defined close to where it is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a function within a loop is wasteful. It will (re)define the function each time because of the `def` keyword. A simple test:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   print(x + 1)
...
>>> id(foo)
1971729284632
>>> def foo(x):
...   print(x + 1)
...
>>> id(foo)
1971739226320
```